# Possible to remove "Shipping Method" from Shopping Cart?

Tags: shopping-cart

Is it possible to remove **"Shipping Method"** programmatically from Shopping Cart (Magento V 1.9)

If I **disable** it from Admin, it does NOT allow completion of Shopping Page Checkout.

**Error Message:** Your Order cannot be completed at this time as there is no Shipping Methods available.  PLs make necessary changes in your address.

Comment: what type of products you are using

Comment: simple , Bundle Configurable type.  Just curious, what has that got to do anything with Shipping Method ?

Comment: Well, for virtual and downloadable products, you don't need a shipping method ;) But you probably want to actually ship products, just not give your customers a choice of shipping method. Thus...

Answer (score 0):

if you add Virtual product or downloadable product then automatically shipping option can be disable.
  And enabled free shipping.